# Unable to cast from ArrayList to ListAdapter

Tags: android

I'm working with fragments and I want to create a list view within the `onCreateView()` method. However I  face some type casting errors in `ArrayList<>`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.view , container , false);

    lv1=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);

    ConnectDatabase db=new ConnectDatabase(getActivity());

    ArrayList<String> theList=new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data=db.retrievee();

    if(data.getCount() == 0)
    {


    }
    else
    {
        while (data.moveToNext())
        {
            theList.add(data.getString(0));

            /*line of Error*/  
            ListAdapter listAdapter=new ArrayList<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theList);

            lv1.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: `ListAdapter listAdapter=new ListAdapter(`

Comment: You're trying to cast an `ArrayList` to a `ListAdapter`, which isn't possible. IntelliJ Amiya has the right idea, use a class that extends `ListAdapter` instead e.g. `ArrayAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
ListAdapter listAdapter=new ArrayList<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theList);
```

with

```
ListAdapter listAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to cast an object to a class it doesn't share a common base with. A `ListAdapter` is used to arrange and present data to a `ListView`, whereas an `ArrayList` is just an ordered collection of other objects and primitives. It's a bit like trying to cast a banana to a telephone, just because they look similar doesn't mean it'll work.

You need to instead declare a class that implements the [`ListAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter) interface. One out-of-the-box option is an [`ArrayAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter?hl=en) as you're already using an `ArrayList<String>` for the list data.

```
ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theList);
lv1.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```